# Change DFP ad position after loading dynamic content

Tags: jquery, google-dfp

I need to insert a DFP ad (Medium Rectangle) in between some dynamic contents. The contents load via AJAX and later populated as below in .items.

```
<div class="items">
  <div>The DFP ad</div>
  <div>New content</div> 
  <div>New content</div> 
  <div>New content</div> 
  <div>New content</div> 
</div>
```

I need the ad to be displayed after third the dynamic content for example. Changing via JS (Jquery) causes erratic ad rendering, mostly just leaving the ad to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

If I got the question correctly you just need to add an ad slot dynamically.

Here's a working example that dynamically creates ad slots:
https://github.com/ffeast/gpt-tests/blob/master/dynamic_slots.html

And here it is live:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lpqtrtgu/

This is the excerpt that creates a new ad slot and renders it:

```
    var slotId = 1;
        function addNewSlot() {
            // add a div containing the dynamic ad
            var label = document.createElement('h1');
            label.innerHTML = 'Dynamic slot #' + slotId;
            document.body.appendChild(label);
            var container = document.createElement('div');
            container.id = 'slot-' + slotId;
            document.body.appendChild(container);
            // dynamic slot creation
            googletag.cmd.push(function() {
                var slot = googletag.defineSlot('/46362926/test_slot1', [240, 400], container.id).addService(googletag.pubads());
                googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display(container.id); googletag.pubads().refresh([slot]); });
            });
            slotId++;
        };
```

The official docs on how to handle such cases in DFP:
https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/4578089?hl=en